# How can I average vectors of different lengths?

Tags: r, prediction, roc

I am trying to average many runs of a randomForest model to produce an average ROC curve.  I am using the pROC and randomForest packages.  Essentially at this point, I want to run the model a thousand times, average the specificity and sensitivity, and plot the average curve.

The problem is that I get different length vectors for specificity and sensitivity each time I run the model.

So I can run it the first time and extract the sens and spec vectors, and will receive a vector of say, 48 numbers.  Then the next time I run it, I might receive 44 numbers.  I can't then just say, run1 + run2, because:

```
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

My current approach is something like:

```
sens1 = get_cur_sens()
sens1
 [1] 2.00000000 1.88558559 1.82522523 1.79189189 1.75855856 1.75855856 1.72522523 1.69819820 1.69819820 1.63783784 1.63783784 1.63783784 1.61081081
[14] 1.55045045 1.52342342 1.52342342 1.46306306 1.40270270 1.37567568 1.37567568 1.34864865 1.31531532 1.31531532 1.28828829 1.26126126 1.23423423
[27] 1.17387387 1.14684685 1.11981982 1.05945946 0.99909910 0.93873874 0.87837838 0.81801802 0.75765766 0.69729730 0.63693694 0.57657658 0.51621622
[40] 0.45585586 0.39549550 0.33513514 0.27477477 0.18738739 0.12702703 0.06666667 1.03333333 0.91891892

length(sens1)
48

#rerun model
sens2 = get_cur_sens()
sens2
  [1] 1.00000 0.96875 0.90625 0.90625 0.90625 0.90625 0.90625 0.90625 0.90625 0.90625 0.90625 0.90625 0.90625 0.87500 0.84375 0.81250 0.81250 0.78125 0.75000
[20] 0.71875 0.71875 0.68750 0.65625 0.62500 0.59375 0.59375 0.59375 0.56250 0.53125 0.50000 0.46875 0.43750 0.40625 0.37500 0.34375 0.31250 0.28125 0.25000
[39] 0.21875 0.18750 0.15625 0.12500 0.09375 0.00000

length(sens2)
44

#I want to do this:
sens = sens1 + sens2
...loop


#After all the runs, just average the vector based on the number of runs.
sens = sens / numRuns
```

So I was thinking it would be great to have the same number of items for each vector, but don't think I can specify that.  Is there a way to, for instance, use the vector to convert to compute a new vector with 100 values?  I need to maintain the integrity of each vector somehow, but also get the averages.

I appreciate any advice anyone can offer.

Comment: If you have a vector [1,2,3] and add [4,5,6,7], you'll get [5,7,9,8] and a warning, because R is having to recycle the first element of the first vector in the addition. You can just add NAs to the shorter vector (up to the desired longer length) and you'll get NA when you average them.

Comment: You should check Fawcett's  introduction to ROC analysis to properly average ROC curves: http://cvrr.ucsd.edu/ece285/papers/Fawcett_IntroductionToROC.pdf